# Can I access Outlook inbox email content with yasoon?

Tags: javascript, email, plugins, outlook

I was creating an Outlook complement with Yasoon, and I want to send emails from the inbox to the server, it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible, great job Yasoon API!
https://github.com/yasoonOfficial/com.yasoon.attachment.export